# Concourse: Resource not found?

Tags: continuous-integration, concourse

I am trying to built a concourse pipeline which is triggered by git, and then runs a script in that git repository.

This is what I have so far:

```html
resources:

- name: component_structure_git
  type: git
  source:
    branch: master
    uri: git@bitbucket.org:foo/bar.git

jobs:
- name: component_structure-docker
  serial: true
  plan:
  - aggregate:
    - get: component_structure_git
      trigger: true
    - task: do-something
      config:
        platform: linux
        image_resource:
          type: docker-image
          source: { repository: ubuntu }
        inputs:
          - name: component_structure_git
        outputs:
          - name: updated-gist  
        run:
          path: component_structure_git/run.sh
  - put: component_structure-docker
    params:
      build: component_structure/concourse

- name: component_structure-deploy-test
  serial: true
  plan:
  - aggregate:
    - get: component_structure-docker
      passed: [component_structure-docker]

- name: component_structure-deploy-prod
  serial: true
  plan:
  - aggregate:
    - get: component_structure-docker
      passed: [component_structure-docker]
```

When I apply this code with fly, everything is ok. When I try to run the build. it fails with the following error:

> missing inputs: component_structure_git

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with first answer. When running things in parallel (aggregate blocks) there are a few things to consider

1. How many inputs do I have? I have more than one, let's run these `get` steps in an aggregate block
2. If I have two tasks, is there a dependency between the tasks that can change the outcome of a task run, eg. Do I have an output from one task that is required in the next task
3. I have a sequence of `put` statements, let's run these steps in an aggregate block

Answer (score 0):

just a guess but aggregate is causing the issue.  You can't have an input from something that is executing at the same time?   Why do you have aggregate anyway?  This is usually used for "get" to speed up the process.